# Как сделать поиск определенной комбинации по битовому массиву?

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Всем привет!! Товарищи, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать поиск определенной комбинации по БИТовому массиву, к примеру такой `01111110`?

Comment: поподробнее опишите задачу

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку вы можете несложно индексировать биты по номеру, задача сводится к поиску подстроки, для которой существует много [известных алгоритмов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Если вам по-простому, попробуйте просканировать массив по кускам размера `(l + 7)` бит, округлённого до целого числа байт (то есть, `(l + 7 + 7) / 8 == (l + 14) / 8`), стартуя с каждого байта, и искать вашу строку со всеми возможными сдвигами от 0 до 7. `l` — битовая длина искомой строки:

```
01001011 11110011 11111101 00111110
```

1)

```
                  11111101 00111110
```

сравниваем с

```
                           01111110
                         0 1111110
                        01 111110
                       011 11110
                      0111 1110
                     01111 110
                    011111 10
                   0111111 0
```

2)

```
         11110011 11111101
```

сравниваем с

```
                  01111110
                0 1111110
               01 111110
              011 11110
             0111 1110
            01111 110
           011111 10
          0111111 0
```

и т. д.

Comment: С математикой все ясно и прозрачно, я этот поиск в коде не могу реализовать!!

Comment: Покажите хоть, что вам удалось сделать.

Comment: Там кода две строчки читаю бинарник в массив, перевожу его в  BitArray, нужно найти в нем  позицию синхрокомбинации  и скопировать с найденой позиции до следующей позиции синхрокомбинации в другой массив и в файл.

Comment: @IGOR: Ну, а что дальше не получается? Опишите, какой вы выбрали алгоритм.